# Merge two columns into one while respecting ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Hello I would like to merge my replace my "Timestamp" column by an outer merge of "Timestamp" and "Timestamp+0.4". Moreover, I would like that my values in the input still correspond to this new "Timestamp" merge column and to have NaNs where the value is not defined (for example 0.6 = NaN in the "input" column)

[image]

My expected output is something like this :

[image]

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

Here is the code to create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[0.2,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.4,1.6,2.0,2.4],
                  'input':[10,20,40,5,15,25,0,20]})
df["Timestamp+0.4"] = df["Timestamp"]+0.4
```

Thanks  a lot !

Comment: How does the other dataframe loook like and what's your expected output?

Comment: @Allen I just edited my post :)

Comment: Are you sure that your desired output is right? My interpretation is that `1.6` should be `25`, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate dataframes along a particular axis. After that [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) the duplicates using only the `Timestamp` column as parameter, then finally sort the values again by the `Timestamp` column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[0.2,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.4,1.6,2.0,2.4],
                   'input': [10, 20, 40, 5, 15, 25, 0, 20]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df["Timestamp"]+0.4)

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
df["Timestamp"] = round(df["Timestamp"], 8)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Timestamp"], keep="first")
df = df.sort_values(["Timestamp"], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Output from **df**

```
    Timestamp  input
0         0.2   10.0
1         0.4   20.0
2         0.6    NaN
3         0.8   40.0
4         1.2    5.0
5         1.4   15.0
6         1.6   25.0
7         1.8    NaN
8         2.0    0.0
9         2.4   20.0
10        2.8    NaN
```

Comment: I think it's a problem with python floating numbers, how they are coded... my solution is to ``` df["Timestamp"] = round(df["Timestamp"],8) ``` right after the first concat so the drop duplicates will work